# Hosting a Might&Magic 7 Online game

Tags: pc, might-and-magic-heroes-7

I'm trying to host a multiplayer game in Heroes: Might & Magic 7 to play it with friends, but they can't join my games and vice versa.

Of course I tried opening the port 20715 (both UDP and TCP) on my Router and my Windows-Firewall but they keep getting the Error Message: "Connection timed out" while trying to join my games.

Is there any hidden port I also need to Open or what could be the reason of it not working?

Also are there maybe any other possibilities of starting a game with my friends online?

Comment: are you guys connecting via IP address or through matchmaking?

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=387672430 will this help

Comment: Some antivirus have firewalls, like Karspensky. You would need to open the port in that firewall too

Comment: @Timelord64 we are connecting through the Game Lobby (1 is Hosting the Game, the other one trying to join)

Comment: Have you port forwarded the following ports?:
TCP/UDP: 27015
Uplay Launcher

TCP: 80, 443, 13000, 14000, 14008

Comment: I'm not sure this constitutes and answer so I'm putting it in a comment: I would suggest LogMeIn Hamachi - It's a VPN software that is great for facilitating online play when there are some connection issues going on. I've had to use this for Terraria and Warcraft III and it worked pretty well.

Comment: @Chase That would be worth turning into an answer, just add some possibly needed details.

Answer (score 1):

Per RavenM's suggestion, I'm turning this into an answer: I would suggest that you try using a VPN/VLAN software like LogMeIn Hamachi in order to accomplish the multi-play while circumventing the port forwarding business that usually accompanies these problems. I've used this software, personally, several times, in order to play Terraria and Warcraft III. Here is a YouTube tutorial on how to download and install Hamachi as well as creating and connecting to a network ([YouTube: Hamachi Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NhNHarE-l4)).

**Keep in mind that any person that you want to be able to play with you will have to download Hamachi and connect using the same connection method in the video (not necessary to create their own network though).**

The video has a download link but I will provide one here to get you started or to at least allow you the ability to research it: [Download page for LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know its an practicable option for you (as it is insecure ^^)

But I had exactly the same problam and even after configuring all as it was expected to be, it didn't work, but it worked after just fully deactivating the firewall.